# How to use Django admin to create custom tasks using Celery

Tags: django, celery, celery-task

I have a Django backend that I've created for a real estate company. I've built quite a few tasks that are hardcoded and I'm wanting to make those tasks customizable via the admin page... but I can't quite figure out how to do that.

For example, let's say that I wanted to create a task that would send an email that could be customized from the admin page. Ideally, I'd have a list of triggers to choose from like a contact form submission.

Something that looked like this:

[image]

Comment: It's not clear. Do you want to know how to create something like Celery? Or want to customize Admin?

Comment: I guess neither. I want to use celery to make relavent customizable tasks via the admin.

Comment: What part is not clear to you? You can create a custom form in admin to trigger some Celery tasks.

Comment: @Ryan Django allows users to create custom forms. Use those forms, and when the form is submitted, you can have custom save method which can trigger relevant tasks based on the input.

Comment: I know that and this isn't what i'm talking about.

Answer (score 2):

I had the very same need on many occasions, and solved it as follows:

1. I have an abstract "base" Task model with a few fields common to any  "generic" background task: created_on, started_on, completed_on, status, progress, failure_reason and a few more
2. When a new specific task is needed, I write:

   - a job function to be run by the scheduler (Celery in your case)
   - a concrete Model derived from Task
3. The derived Model knows which job has to be run; this is hardcoded in the Model definition; **I also add specific fields to collect any custom parameter required by the job**
4. Now, you can create a new task either programmatically or from the Django admin, supplying actual parameters as needed; in the latter case, Django provides the required form and validation as usual

After saving the new record in the database, the model kicks off the job, passing by the task (model) id; **from the job you can retrieve task's details**: which is the answer to the original question.
You can also update the progress/status in the model for later inspection, and use other services provided by the base class (for example, logging).

This schema has been proven very useful, since, as an added benefit, you can monitor async tasks from the Django admin.

Having used it in several projects, I encapsulated this logic in a reusable Django app:

https://github.com/morlandi/django-task

The current implementation is based on `rq`, as `Celery` is over-engineered for my needs. I guess it can be adapted to `Celery` with some modifications:

- remove Task.check_worker_active_for_queue()
- remove Task.get_queue()
- refactor Task.run()

Additionally, the helper Job class must be refactored as follows:

- replace rq.get_current_job() with the equivalent for Celery

Unfortunately, I haven't used Celery recently, so I can't give more detailed advices.

Comment: This is conceptually what I'm looking for, but I'm looking through the code and I can't quite see how to swap the rq integration with celery

Comment: Hmmm, I understand ... I was far too optimistic when I wrote "it can be adapted to Celery with few modifications"; I do apologize for that. I'll change my answer to better reflect this